# Remap last autocompletion word

Tags: key-bindings

I want to map `Ctrl-M` to go to the last autocompletion word. Currently, `Ctrl-P` does this. In my `.vimrc`:

```
inoremap <c-m> <c-p>
```

And this adds the functionality I want.

However, if I'm in *insert mode* and hit `Enter`, this also triggers the autocompletion.

Happens in both macVim and CLI vim.

Comment: In Vim (or in terminal), `<c-m>` inserts Carriage Return /CR (Enter) (and `<c-j>`, a newline (NL) ). See `:h CTRL-M` and `:h i_CTRL-M`, or this answer: http://superuser.com/questions/433903/how-to-type-carriage-return